# Python: Close a file opened with scipy.misc.imread

Tags: python, scipy, filesystems, file-descriptor

In Python one can read in an image with scipy like so:

```
from scipy.misc import imread

img = imread('cats.jpg')
```

How can one close that opened file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Scipy uses PIL under the cover, and PIL supports a `with` block syntax that automatically closes the file when the block is exited:

```
from PIL import Image

with Image.open('test.png') as test_image:
    do_things(test_image)
```